Change Zoom Virtual Background on Ubuntu
When I try to change the virtual background on zoom on Ubuntu, my camera freezes (on Windows, I have no problems). I've already search  on google and tried all solutions proposed but I still have the same problem. Could anyone help me? Thank you
